# Error on using User location

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Why do I cannot use the user location? I already added the key on `Info.plist`, however when I run the app, I didn't receive the message. What might be happening?

[image]

I tested on my IPhone, I'm just posting the simulator image for you guys check what I got.

[image: I tested on my IPhone, I'm just posting the simulator image for you guys check]

Comment: You need to write code to get user current location, at very first time it will ask for permission and show that message from info.plist, above effort not show popup as you want.

Comment: Hello! The problem is that the App isn't asking for permition

Comment: Please read my comment you need to proper code for that after it asking for permission. The code you post it will not show any alert because it just use for alert MESSAGE, not to fetch user's location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the info.plist file

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Application needs permission to access your current location.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Application needs permission to access your current location.</string>
```

And Use below code to get your location

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation: CLLocation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
}

// Handle incoming location events.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
    print("Location: \(location)")
}


// Handle authorization for the location manager.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .restricted:
        print("Location access was restricted.")
    case .denied:
        print("User denied access to location.")
    case .notDetermined:
        print("Location status not determined.")
    case .authorizedAlways: fallthrough
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        print("Location status is OK.")

    }
}

// Handle location manager errors.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working. When I run the app, the location message doesn't appear.